# How can I display only a certain v-for item in vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, youtube-api

How can I display only a certain v-for item in vue js? I'm pulling youtube data api items using v-for. Within these items is an iframe that I'd like to 'activate' when a user clicks on a play button. Right now all the iframes on the page display when the button is clicked, but I'd only like the specific video clicked.

```
<v-card v-for="video in videos" :key="video.snippet.resourceId.videoId">
  <iframe
    v-if="videoPlaying"
    :src="ytEmbedUrl + video.snippet.resourceId.videoId"
    frameborder="0"
    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in- 
picture" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>

<v-btn round @click="videoPlaying = true">
        <v-icon dark>play_arrow</v-icon>
        <span slot="loader" class="custom-loader">
          <v-icon light>cached</v-icon>
        </span>
      </v-btn>
</v-card>

data (){
return {
videoPlaying: null
}
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: `@click="videos[video][videoPlaying] = true"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need only one video, then on click you should assign the chosen video to one property, something like:

```js
data: {
  videos: [...],
  selected: null
}
```

```
<iframe
  v-if="selected"
  :src="ytEmbedUrl + selected.snippet.resourceId.videoId"
  frameborder="0"
  allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" 
  allowfullscreen>
</iframe>

<v-card v-for="video in videos" :key="video.snippet.resourceId.videoId">
  <v-btn round @click="selected = video">
    <v-icon dark>play_arrow</v-icon>
    <span slot="loader" class="custom-loader">
      <v-icon light>cached</v-icon>
    </span>
  </v-btn>
</v-card>
```

and just show only selected video.

But if your condition is more advanced or you want to choose several videos, you should use computed property with filtering:

```
data: {
  all_videos: [...]
},
computed: {
  videos() {
    return this.all_videos.filter((video) => your_condition);
  }
}
```

[Here](https://medium.com/devmarketer/how-to-add-conditional-statements-to-v-for-loops-in-vue-js-c0b4d17e7dfd) you can read more.

Comment: I've implemented the above example, but I'm still getting every card opening their specific video when I click any play button. I think I screwed up the computed

    computed: {
    selectedVideo() {
      return this.videos.filter(video => {
        return video.selected;
      });
    }
  },

Comment: hmm .. I need to see your template - can you create a [codepen](https://codepen.io/) with your code ?

Comment: Thank you for the help. Here's a fiddle. The goal is to have whatever play button is clicked, that image is replaced with an iframe showing the video.

https://jsfiddle.net/bobdempsey83/7smyfu1z/30/

Comment: I updated your fiddle. I just changed iframe _if_ to: `<iframe v-if="selected === video"` and I added `v-show="selected !== video"` to `<img ... />`. It seems work to me :)

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks @Beniamin H !